# How can I make it so that everytime constructor is going to get called?

Tags: controller-extension

I have a page A contains another page B by apex:include. however when every I tried to refresh the page using rerender the constructor won't get called. page b has a standard controller and extensions specified. What's the best way so that extension's constructor get called whenever I refresh the page?

Comment: You can't call constructors more than once per view state. What is your intended objective? There are ways to accomplish your goal without calling constructors each time.

Comment: I wonder if a page action might work here.

Comment: apex:page action is only invoked on HTTP GET.

Comment: I wanted to display different object list which is linking to the page a's standard controller. I ended up using the component and pass the id.

Comment: @ShinyaKoizumi can you post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can reference it? Thanks!